# 2D array and creating a mirror of an image

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, computer-science

I'm supposed to create an image editor using 2D arrays.  For this part I'm supposed to create code that creates a mirror of the image by flipping it left to right. Instead I'm flipping it upside down. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void mirror() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] img;
    int left = 0, right = data.length -1;
    while (right >= left) {
        img = data[left];
        data[left++] = data[right];
        data[right--] = img;
    }       
}
```

Comment: what is data and what is its data structure? also, you're not using a 2d array.

Comment: Is this image ascii art? If so, you need a multi-dimensional array don't you? X/Y coords so 2D? Unless it's a 1D image?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Problems:
1. You're using a 1D Array.
2. `data.length` on 1d array gives you number of rows.
3. Now when you use `data.length` for reversing, you end up revering rows instead of columns in 2d array.
Hence your logically incorrect output.

Use mirror method should be something like this -

```
public int[][] mirror(int[][] original) {
     int[][] mirror = original;
     for (int i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
         original[i] = reverseArray(original[i]);
     }
     return mirror;
}


public int[] reverseArray(int[] array) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you were just mirroring the arrays that made up the matrix, rather than reversing the order of the arrays. Assuming `data` was in fact a 2D array to begin with, this should work for you.

```
public void mirror() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length/2; j++){
            int temp = data[i][j];
            data[i][j] = data[i][data[i].length-j-1];
            data[i][data[i].length-j-1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way than the other answers in my opinion:

```
int[][] mirrored = new int[data.length][data[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mirrored[i][data[i].length - j - 1] = data[i][j];
    }
}
```